# CSS expand a list inside a two column block to the full row height while have a dynamic-size image in the second column

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have a block with a fixed width and a max height size. I need to place into this block two elements: a list and a dynamic size image.
They are have to be at one level like a columns in a table. The list have to be a 20% width of the main block, and image - 80% width.
The image would change its size when the windows width would decrease.
And I need that the list fills whole row height preserving the equal height for each list item.

Can I achieve that only with a help of CSS? Also I don't want to use `display: grid` and `display: flex` to resolve browser compatibility issue.
Also discarding `ui li` in favor of representing each list item as a simple `div` is impossible or too complicated solution in that case.

If it is only possible with the help of `grid` or `flex` then I will appreciate such solution in any case.

An example:
https://jsfiddle.net/Eugenii10/y0otpo2e/2/

What I want to get:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UqTG.jpg

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished with flex-box

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/9ty5wqcd/)

```
#wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
}

#firstCol { width: 28%; }

#firstCol ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
}

#firstCol ul > li {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#firstCol ul > li > a {
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  text-align: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 1rem 0;
}

#secondCol {}

#secondCol img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It is working. I have changed some part to remove manual padding in `#firstCol ul > li > a`: https://jsfiddle.net/Eugenii10/3k9gxzt6/